# select with update sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Alter Proc K_RT_BranchWiseBirdsStock
@branch varchar(50)

as
begin

select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.branch) as sno,b.sno as keys,
d.branch,a.transferbirds,b.noofbirds,c.noofbirds,e.mortality,
(a.transferbirds-b.noofbirds-c.noofbirds-e.mortality) as finalbirds from    
K_RT_RetailsDetails a 
inner join K_RT_WarehouseDetails b on a.branch = b.branch
inner join K_RT_MasterBirdsTransferDet c on a.branch = c.frombranch 
inner join K_RT_MasterRetailStores d on d.sno = a.branch
inner join K_RT_DailyEntry e on e.branch = d.sno
where d.branch = @branch

update K_RT_RetailsDetails set transferbirds = finalbirds where branch = @branch
end
```

here i want to fill the column transferbirds = finalbirds...here finalbirds is a alias name.how can i update that column..please help me

Comment: will select return single row or many rows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
ALTER Proc K_RT_BranchWiseBirdsStock
@branch varchar(50)

as
begin


declare @final_birds varchar(255)
declare @snum varchar(50)
declare @key varchar(50)
declare @branches varchar(50)
declare @transfbirds varchar(50)
declare @numofbirdsb varchar(50)
declare @numofbirdsc varchar(50)
declare @mortal varchar(50)


select  @snum=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.branch) ,
@key=b.sno,
@branches=d.branch,
@transfbirds=a.transferbirds,
@numofbirdsb=b.noofbirds,
@numofbirdsc=c.noofbirds,
@mortal= e.mortality,
@final_birds=(a.transferbirds-b.noofbirds-c.noofbirds-e.mortality)
from    
K_RT_RetailsDetails a 
inner join K_RT_WarehouseDetails b on a.branch = b.branch
inner join K_RT_MasterBirdsTransferDet c on a.branch = c.frombranch 
inner join K_RT_MasterRetailStores d on d.sno = a.branch
inner join K_RT_DailyEntry e on e.branch = d.sno
where d.branch = @branch

update K_RT_RetailsDetails set transferbirds = @final_birds where branch = @branch
end
```

try this, for answer purpose i have used varchar(50) for every declared variable, you should update it with its respective datatype as you have declared while creating table. this query has executed at my site without any error

Comment: seems like you have to remove alias, and have to declare variables for each column that you are selecting in query..

Comment: @SambaSiva check my edited query, and let me know if it works